# Tabledit con jquery no funciona bien

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Estoy tratando de aprender a crear tablas editables con jquery.tabledit.min.js pero real mente no estoy museguro de donde esta fallando mis sentencias.

Mi tabla "testC" es:

```
id fisrt  last
1  juan   a
2  pedro  b
3  diago  c
```

y mi index que estoy tratando de hacer funcionar (para editar despues y agregar informacion de mi proyecto):

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo ); 
//mi conecion a BD esta esta en sql server sqlsrv

$query = "SELECT * FROM testC ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
<script src="jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>
//las librerias , tengo ya en mi carpeta el documento con jquery

    <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php

     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
      echo '
      <tr>
       <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["fisrt"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["last"].'</td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
//la tabla anote mal first y puse fisrt pero lo e dejado asi por cuestiones de 
//ser una tabla test

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
      url:'action.php',
      columns:{
       identifier:[0, "id"],
       editable:[[1, 'fisrt'], [2, 'last']]
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.action == 'edit')
       {
        $('#'+data.id).remove();
       }
      }
     });

});  
 </script>
```

y este es mi codigo action.php:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo );

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

$query = "SELECT * FROM testC WHERE fisrt=? AND last=?";
$parameters = [$_POST["fisrt"], $_POST["last"]];
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parameters);


if($input["action"] === 'edit')
{
 $query_edit = "UPDATE testC 
                   SET fisrt = '$first_name', 
                       last = '$last_name' 
                   WHERE id = '$input["id"]'";

 sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

}
if($input["action"] === 'delete')
{
 $query_del = "DELETE FROM testC WHERE id = '".$input["id"]."'";sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

 sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_del);

}
echo json_encode($input);

?>
```

actual mente muestra la informacion de mi base de datos y tabla pero al mandar un edit borra los campos . cual seria el problema?

Comment: Sera este el problema: `$('#'+data.id).remove();`

Comment: eso pensaba pero no a echo cambio alguno quitarlo incluso en action.php cambie el delete por una copia del update pero solo borra o hace nada

Comment: Intenta quitar un signo de igual cuando comparas la action.  `==` en lugar de `===`

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :( con o sin el signo de igual

Comment: creo que real mente no esta pasando los parametros al action.php

Comment: añade estas líneas antes de **onSuccess**, y mira si en la consola se estan pasando los parámetros.  onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
        console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
        console.log(action);
        console.log(serialize);
    },